# Compiling ChromeDriver on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I'm trying to compile ChromeDriver from: https://github.com/bayandin/chromedriver, the instructions says:

"Build ChromeDriver by building the 'chromedriver' target. This will
create an executable binary in the build folder named"

How can I do that? I've spent some hours trying to do it, but all I have found are instructions for compiling the Chromium itself. I'm not familiar with .gn files, do I have to compile the entire Chromium project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to the src directory, and execute the following:

```
gn gen out\chromedriver
ninja -C out\chromedriver chromedriver
```

The first step will create an output directory for this build. The second step will build chromedriver target to the specified output directory.